Probability of random vector
We choose 100 points on interval $(0,1).$ If $X_1$ is the number of points from $(0,0.5)$ and $X_2$ is the number of points from $(0.4,0.7)$ find distribution for random vector $(X_1,X_2)$.
I suppose that number of points from $(0,4, 0.5)$ is $s$, then $P\{X_1=k,X_2=l\}=\sum_{s=0}^{\min(k,l)}\binom{100}{s}\frac{1}{10^s}\binom{100-s}{k}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{100-s-k}{l}\frac{1}{5^k}\frac{1}{3^{100-k-l+s}}$
Is this okay? Can this be simplified?

You also have to consider points on (0.7, 1)

I did, that is the last part of equation $\frac{1}{3^{100-k-l-s}}$

Why do you have $\frac{1}{10^s}\cdot \frac{1}{4^k}\cdot \frac{1}{5^k}\cdot \frac{1}{3^{100-k-l+s}}$ rather than ${0.1^s}\cdot {0.4^{k-s}}\cdot {0.2^{l-s}}\cdot {0.3^{100-k-l+s}}$ ?  And why $\binom{100-s}{k}\cdot \binom{100-s-k}{l}$ rather than  $\binom{100-s}{k-s}\cdot \binom{100-s-k}{l-s}$ ? You also need to restrict yourself to cases where $k\ge 0, l \ge 0, k+l \le 100$

That seems abouttiarallaa correct: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/baoptghnfd But why is it too small/big (doesn't sum to one) I might have had the conditional histogram there but what do you divide by?!??
